# How to parse xml file with YII

Tags: xml, yii

I have a field with `text` name in table. One row of this table is:

```
<message type="chat"
         id="purple6ba21864" 
         to="10713@172.30.12.44/e859f0e7" 
         from="10735@172.30.12.44/qutecom">

<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
<body>test</body>
<thread>aaaa</thread>
</message>
```

result:
`testaaaa`

I need to show just 'test'.

Comment: Same as in any other PHP framework? `simplexml_load_string` / `DOMDocument`, or consult [the manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) for more options...

Comment: @DCoder sorry, question has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this time (version 1.1.13) Yii does not provide any helper classes to work with XML data, even though there are situations where XML-based functionality is an obvious omission (for example, a hypothetical `CXmlDataProvider`).

For the time being you will have to work with XML manually using the standard PHP APIs (simplexml, DOMDocument, etc) or a third-party XML library.